# Reading pop3 mails using OpenPop.Net

Tags: c#, pop3, openpop

I'm usging OpenPop.Net to access mail with C# app. 
I want to be able to mark the mails I handled using this app, without deleting/removing this mails. another problem is that I can't take only the unread mails, because there's other application / peoples that access this mail.
Is there's any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop3 protocol doesn't allow to mark anything on server. All emails can be marked only locally on your machine. All email clients using Pop3 have its own mark as read logic and this is done based local  client database. You do not need to worry about other client used by users. Just download emails and store messageid somewhere locally maybe some other additional info as well. Then based on that process only not existing in local database emails.

Comment: There is an example of how to do this using OpenPop.NET [here](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleDownloadUnread.php). Also, The IMAP protocol might be what you are really looking for.